# Include TabBarIOS on each page of React native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-native, tabbar

In my react native application, I define TabBarIOS tabs in a HomePage component. Upon clicking various tabs, functions are called that load components from other classes that are associated with these tabs. However, if I use a navigator within these components to push a new screen, the TabBarIOS disappears (as expected), and I can't figure out how to rework this so it remains visible on all child screens of these components. I've included relevant code; any advice would be greatly appreciated!

TabBarIOS rendering:

```
  render: function() {
return (
  <TabBarIOS
    tintColor="white"
    barTintColor="#cee4dc">
    <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
      title="PROFILE"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.profile}
      iconName="ios-profile"
      selectedIconName="ios-profile"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: TABS.profile,
        });
      }}>
     {this._renderProfile()}
    </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
    <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
      title="HOME"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.home}
      iconName="ios-home"
      selectedIconName="ios-home"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: TABS.home,
        });
      }}>
     {this._renderHome()}
    </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
    <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
      title="FEED"
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.feed}
      iconName="ios-feed"
      selectedIconName="ios-feed"
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: TABS.feed,
        });
      }}>
     {this._renderFeed()}
    </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
  </TabBarIOS>
);
},
```

Rendering specific tab components:

```
  _renderFeed: function(){
      return(
        <Feed navigator = {this.props.navigator} />
      );
    },
 _renderHome: function(){
      return(
        <Home navigator = {this.props.navigator} />
      );
    },
 _renderProfile: function(){
      return(
        <Profile navigator = {this.props.navigator} />
      );
    },
```

Navigator to next component in HomePage upon ListView rowPressed:

```
rowPressed: function(hunt) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: "Item",
        component: ItemOverview,
        passProps: {
            item: item,
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want Tabbar will show in every view, right?
You need a router for help it more efficient.

Try to use the [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to support you, and tabbar has be supported in this router solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the native iOS tab bar to persist on every view then it needs to be higher in the view hierarchy than the navigator, so basically instead of having `Navigator` -> `TabBarIOS` you would have a new `Navigator` in each `_render*` function making your view hierarchy something like this:

```
TabBarIOS
  Navigator
    Feed
  Navigator
    Home
  Navigator
    Profile
```

If you don't think this is a good solution, I'd suggest you take a look at `NavigationExperimental`. It's poorly documented at the moment, so [the examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/NavigationExperimental) are probably your best bet.